# spring-boot when return using ResponEntity get respon : no content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

i want to read some data from database, and using `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity` as response class using API, when i return API using String its look fine but when i change return using ResponseEntity..i always get response code 500 :no content to map due to end-of-input

here my controller class i'm using

```
import com.access.cargo.placement.config.JwtConstants;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class AcceptanceRestController {

@Autowired
    AwbService awbService;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/awb-koli/{code}/scan", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity getStorageBin(@RequestHeader(value = JwtConstants.TOKEN_HEADER) String token, @PathVariable("code") Long code) {
        authClient.authenticate(token);

        Collection<String> authRoles = new LinkedList<>();
        authRoles.add("ROLE_OUTGOING_ADMIN");
        authRoles.add("ROLE_OUTGOING_ACCEPTANCE");
        if (!isAuthorized(token, authRoles)) {
            String msg = "You dont have authorization....";
            return new ResponseEntity<>(msg, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        AwbKoli resp = new AwbKoli();
        resp = awbService.getAwbKoli(token, code);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(resp, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

here my repo

```
import com.access.cargo.awb.model.entity.AwbKoli;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository
public interface AwbRepo extends JpaRepository<AwbKoli, Long> {

    AwbKoli findFirstByAwbKoliAndState(AwbKoli awbKoli, Integer state);

}
```

here my service

```
import com.access.cargo.awb.repo.AwbRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AwbService {

    @Autowired
    AwbRepo repo;

public AwbKoli getAwbKoli(Long id) {
        return repo.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }


}
```

here my entity

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "awb_koli")
@DynamicUpdate
public class AwbKoli implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -805351090352429123L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "awb", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Awb awb;

}
```

here my configuration

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_access_cargo?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
#___JPA:
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace
```

and here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.access.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>acceptance</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>acceptance-service</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>access-cargo-acceptance-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this result API, i always get

[image: resultAPI]

**Curl**
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/access-cargo-acceptance-service/awb-koli/231/scan" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhdXRoLXRva2VuIiwiYXVkIjoiRlJPTlRFTkRfV0VCIiwidWlkIjoiYWRtaW4uYWdlbnQjMSIsImlzcyI6IkFDQ0VTU19DQVJHTyIsImV4cCI6MTU4NDIxNTA0MywicmlkIjoicXdlcnR5IiwiaWF0IjoxNTg0MTU1MDQzfQ.GpBfRMFoK--vU1L9ddx1H3B4KixbB4zFslyKYXerVDBTjELSbeGZsdKzzQDx7RsaOu757zxO8LtHtR3bO5vAIw"

**Request URL**
http://localhost:8080/access-cargo-acceptance-service/awb-koli/231/scan

**Server response**
Code    Details
500 *Undocumented*

**Error:**
Response body
Download
No content to map due to end-of-input

**Response headers**
 cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
 connection: close 
 content-length: 37 
 content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 
 date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 11:03:09 GMT 
 expires: 0 
 pragma: no-cache 
 x-content-type-options: nosniff 
 x-frame-options: DENY 
 x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

**Responses**
Code    Description
200 OK

**Example Value**
Model
{
  "body": {},
  "statusCode": "100 CONTINUE",
  "statusCodeValue": 0
}

```
i dont know what to fix this...please anyone help..
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring's document, ResponseEntity like ResponseBody, It use HttpMessageConverter to serialize the return value, and if you return String value, it will write to response without convertion.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson mapping requires a default constructor. Just add `@NoArgsConstructor` to your AwbKoli class.